# Neo4j Cypher : replace multiple characters

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i need to replace multiple characters by single character

```
RETURN LOWER(REPLACE("ranchod-das-chanchad-240190---Funshuk--Wangdu",'--', '-'))
```

is there any regex to do this

*for neo4j 2.2.2*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no function similar to `REPLACE` taking a regex as a parameter.

Since you're using Neo4j 2.2, you can't implement it as a procedure either.

The only way to do it is by splitting and joining (using a combination of `reduce` and `substring`):

```
RETURN substring(reduce(s = '', e IN filter(e IN split('ranchod-das-chanchad-240190---Funshuk--Wangdu', '-') WHERE e <> '') | s + '-' + e), 1);
```

It can be easier to read if you decompose it:

```
WITH split('ranchod-das-chanchad-240190---Funshuk--Wangdu', '-') AS elems
WITH filter(e IN elems WHERE e <> '') AS elems
RETURN substring(reduce(s = '', e IN elems | s + '-' + e), 1);
```